# Empty footnoteline on next page

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have added a footnote including only an URL to page 2 of my document (3 pages in total).

> \footnote{\url{google.de}}

This works as expected, but, there is an empty footnoteline on page 3. If i add another page (\newpage), there is no footnoteline on page 4.

If I change the footnotetext to some letters, like "abc", the problem remains (so it is not the length or the \url within the footnote). Adding a second footnote is not changing anything. Adding a footnote to page 3 does not produce an empty footnoteline on page 4.

Can I somehow prevent the creation of a footnotearea/footnoteline?

Ah, obviously I forgot the main aspect: I am within a tabularx environment. The footnote is completely correct (place and number etc.) but an empty line on page 3 is created. That's the only problem.
Lastly, a footnote on page 1 within a tabularx works fine (no line on page 2 or 3).

Minimal working example can be found in the following comment:
[Empty footnoteline on next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347789/empty-footnoteline-on-next-page?noredirect=1#comment854060_347789)

Comment: `tabularx` uses multiple passes on the table to calculate the widths of the `X` columns. So if you have a footnote inside it, it will also be processed multiple times. This may be the cause of the problem. My suggestion would be to put `\footnotemark` inside the `tabularx` and `\footnotetext` outside of it.

Comment: Produces the same outcome. The footnote on page 2 is correct, on page 3 a blank line appears :/

Comment: Can you give a MWE ([minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a033a0b7b53dea838d3bb17217977636
I found out, that if the last tabularx on page2 spans over to page3 it disappears. so if you add a &\\ to the tabular "f" at the end, the line disappears (would also move table g more down). however, lets assume that is my exact .tex i want to compile without the line on page3 :)